# Add generator to project

Tags: swift, storyboard, qr-code

I have a swift struct:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import CoreImage.CIFilterBuiltins

    struct Qrview : View {
        let context = CIContext()
        let filter = CIFilter.qrCodeGenerator()
        var url : String
        
        var body: some View {
            Image(uiImage: genearteQrcodeimage(url: url))
        }
        func genearteQrcodeimage(url : String) -> UIImage {
            let data = Data(url.utf8)
            filter.setValue(data, forKey: "Inputmessage")
            if let qrcodeImage = filter.outputImage {
                if let qrcodeImage  = context.createCGImage(qrcodeImage, from: qrcodeImage.extent){
                    return UIImage(cgImage: qrcodeImage)
                    
                }
            }
            return UIImage(systemName: "mark") ?? UIImage()
        }
    }
```

and a view controller:

```
import UIKit


    class ViewController: UIViewController {
        @IBOutlet weak var QRImage: UIView!
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        }
    
    
    }
```

According to this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bKOdFVirgU0

It will generate a qrcodeimage.
How can I add this generated qrcodeimage to my view (QRImage) created in storyboard.

Comment: Move your `genearteQrcodeimage` outside your views, e.g. to a service class or an extension on `UIImage`. Then just call it from your controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the view by using UIHostingController. First, you need to import swiftUI in your viewcontroller as below:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class EventsViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var QRImage: UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Example of use
        let childView = UIHostingController(rootView: Qrview(url: "www.google.com"))
        addChild(childView)
        childView.view.frame = QRImage.bounds
        QRImage.addSubview(childView.view)
        childView.didMove(toParent: self)
    }

}
```

BTW, you need to set frame and filter key from your SwiftUI view. Becareful about the key-value name (case sensitive):

> filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import CoreImage.CIFilterBuiltins

    struct Qrview : View {
        let context = CIContext()
        let filter = CIFilter.qrCodeGenerator()
        var url : String
        
        var body: some View {
            Image(uiImage: genearteQrcodeimage(url: url))
                .resizable().frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .center)
        }
        func genearteQrcodeimage(url : String) -> UIImage {
            let data = Data(url.utf8)
            filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
            if let qrcodeImage = filter.outputImage {
                if let qrcodeImage  = context.createCGImage(qrcodeImage, from: qrcodeImage.extent){
                    return UIImage(cgImage: qrcodeImage)
                    
                }
            }
            return UIImage(systemName: "mark") ?? UIImage()
        }
    }
```

Here is the output:
[image]